# Elastic Search compare query for search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm working with ElasticSearch and I have index with following documents:

```
{"distancestart": 1.34, "distanceend": 1.52, "event": "case1"}, 
{"distancestart": 1.7, "distanceend": 1.85, "event": "case2"}, 
{"distancestart": 7.91, "distanceend": 8.36, "event": "case3"}, 
{"distancestart": 12.2, "distanceend": 14.85, "event": "case1"}
{"distancestart": 22.2, "distanceend": 24.85, "event": "case2"}...... so on
```

I would like to create a query base on "distancestart" & "event" -
e.g. "case1" near "case2" (order doesn't matter) where difference between start distance of case1 & case2 shouldn't be more than "2.0"

in above set it should return me -

```
{"distancestart": 1.34, "distanceend": 1.52, "event": "case1"}, 
{"distancestart": 1.7, "distanceend": 1.85, "event": "case2"}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried span_near query but that gives me result for case1 near case2 but I need to add condition on distancestart between those two cases, I have tried script query also but it's not working in this case